# How to populate a dropdown in a dynamic appended div with database value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to create a dropdown in my appended div using php,mysql and ajax but its not working for me.The javascript code is below where city and locality is coming from ajax and php and create in a dynamic div on + button click:
Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;
$("#addButton").click(function () {
        if (counter > 19) {
            alert("Only 20 Address allowed");
            return false;
        }


    var elems = '<div class="col-lg-5"  id="Address' + counter + '">'+
          '<textarea class="form-control" name="alt_address[]" rows="3" placeholder="Address' + (counter+1) + '" /><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' +
          '<div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="city' + counter + '">'+
          '<select name="city_name[]" id="city_name' + counter + '" class="form-control"></select>' +
          '</div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group"><select name="locality_name[]" id="locality_name' + counter + '" class="form-control"><option value="" selected="selected" >Select Locality</option></select></div></div>' + 
          '<div class="col-lg-1 form-group">'+
          '<button type="button" class="removebtn" id="removeButton' + counter + '">' +
          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>' +
          '</div><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' ;


    $('#addressDiv').append(elems);

        counter++;

         $.ajax({

        type:"Post",

        url:"city_load.php",



        cache:"false",

        success:function(html){

            $("#locality_name" + counter).html(html);

        }

        });

         return false;
         });

         $("#city_name" + counter).change(function(){



    $city_id = $(this).val();



    $.ajax({

        type:"Post",

        url:"ajax-dd3ck.php",

        data:"city_id="+$city_id,

        cache:"false",

        success:function(html){

            $("#locality_name" + counter).html(html);

        }

        });

    });



                $(document).on('click','.removebtn',function () {

                if(counter==0){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#Address" + counter).remove();
    $("#removeButton" + counter).remove();






});


});
```

Comment: city_load.php: <?php
 include("db.php");
   $sql="select * from city";

      $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
      {

                 echo "<option value='$row[city_id]'>$row[city_name]</option>";
        
                   }
       
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax is incorrect:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
     echo "<select name='city_name' id='city_name'$i class='form-control'>";
{
```

That should be

```
echo "<select name='city_name' id='city_name'$i class='form-control'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
```

The `id='city_name'$i` also is an `HTML` error but shouldn't affect the PHP.

You don't actually use `$i` anywhere else or increment it so I'm not sure why you actually have that..

Comment: I have corrected my syntax error and tried but the city box is not coming when I click on + sign.I have appended div for city like below:<div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="city' + counter +'"></div> thats why i have added $i.Please help me here

Comment: Does the ajax request return with the `select`? The `$i` should be inside the single quote; outside puts it outside the attribute value.

Comment: is there any way to create a dropdown list in a dynamic created div when dropdown is populating from database value and it have a cascade dropdown like my code above.Please see screenshot on  
 
snag.gy/AIA9k.jpg

Comment: Chris-Ajax doesnt come with select tag of city using in city_load.php.please suggest a solution

Comment: Does it make the ajax request? If so does it return anything or does the page throw a 500?

Comment: The drop down values are not coming in city and then locality dropdown gets filled on change event of city in dynamic appended div.

Comment: My main question is that how can I repeat the elements in appended div(dynamic created div) which gets added on + button